# "GenerateWinPRTManifest" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to build a WP8 app and I keep getting the following error:

Any ideas?

```
Error   12  The "GenerateWinPRTManifest" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifest.IsManifestUptoDate()
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifest.SaveDocumentIfUpdated()
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifest.ExecuteImplementation()
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.GenerateWinPRTManifest.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong but deleting the contents of the Bin and obj folder and rebuilding resolved the issue.